# prove $[Av]_s = P^{-1} AP[v]_s$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $S= \{v_1,...,v_n\}$ be a basis for $ \Bbb R^n $ and $P = [v_1\cdots v_n] $ where $v_j$ is column vector . Prove that for any square matrix A of order n and column vector V, 
$$[Av]_s = P^{-1} AP [v]_s$$

I don't even know how to start, can someone kindly give a hint? Thanks! 
Sorry for the formatting if it is wrong...

Comment: Latex is much simpler as it seems on the first spot, you can learn it in 5 minutes.

Comment: @peterh sorry it was sent before I finish. Thx for ur comment

Answer (score 1):

That looks like my homework (which is probably late by now). The hint states that $P$ is the transition matrix from $S$ to the standard basis $E$.

This means that for any column vector $u$:

$$P[u]_S=u$$

Hence:

> $[Av]_S=P^{-1}P[Av]_S=P^{-1}Av=P^{-1}AP[v]_S$

Comment: haha, yes it's homework. Anyway, I summit alr. ;P